# Long org-export latex header

Tags: org-export, latex

I need many lines in my org-export latex header.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[main=british,polutonikogreek]{babel}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fontspec}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{hanging}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainfont{ebgaramond}[Contextuals=Alternate]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcount\instr \instr=1 % hide/show instructions
#+LATEX_HEADER: \babelhyphenation[british]{philo-sophy}
```

Is there an alternative to putting `#+LATEX_HEADER` in front of each?

Comment: Your problem is not related with the tile of the question.

Comment: If you prefer, write all of the preamble in an external file, say `header.tex`, and then call it like `#+latex_header: /path/to/header.tex`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A possible solution is to write a file with the LaTeX preamble, like

```
%% This is the file MyTeXHeader.tex
\usepackage[main=british,polutonikogreek]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hanging}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond}[Contextuals=Alternate]
\newcount\instr \instr=1 % hide/show instructions
\babelhyphenation[british]{philo-sophy}
```

and then use a single call of `#+latex_header` in your org file

```
#+title: A shortcut in my LaTeX header
#+author: Stan Lee
#+latex_header: \input{/path/to/your/MyTeXHeader.tex}

* Introduction
  bla bla bla
```

Comment: I had to do `#+latex_header: \input preamble`

Comment: @toothrot: I corrected the call of the file. Thx!

Comment: This is very helpful, because you can easily play with the headerfile without reloading your .emacs every time *plus* you can comment out lines in the header file! Commenting out in the .emacs may or may not work with `%`, however, the usual `;` inside the LaTeX header causes strange effects.